# c++ Gomoku diagonal checker

Tags: c++, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, gomoku

so I am a relatively new to coding. So I have to make a Gomoku game for a project. Gomoku is like tic-tac-toe, but have to get five in a row. Have been given certain restrictions such as a board size of 6x6 to 15x15. The use of at least one class. I have chosen to use arrays. I have created PlayerOne as an algorithm which bases its moves on PlayerOne's last move, and moves one random block away from it in next move. The second algorithm is random. For when checking for a win, my horizontal and vertical checkers seem to work but both my diagonal checkers are giving problems, with them saying that 3 consecutive blocks in a row diagonally is 5 in a row. I created my checkers separately, filling in each row manually to test, and the diagonal checkers were fine there, but they're not fine in the whole code.
I'll share both the diagonal checkers up here, and then the whole code a little below so hopefully easier to read. Also quite a bit of it has cout statements as was trying to see where problems where earlier in the process. If anyone can see where the issue is occurring if could point out where, would be so appreciative.

```
int game::diagonalCheckerNegSlope(int arr[15][15], int size) {
    int count1;
    int count2;
    int whoWon = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        count1 = 0;
        count2 = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[j][i] == 1) {

                for (int d = 0; (i + d < size) && (j + d < size); d++)
                    if (arr[i + d][j + d] == 1) {
                        count1++;
                        if (count1 == 5) {
                            whoWon = 1;
                        }
                    } else {
                        count1 = 0;
                    }

            }
            if (arr[j][i] == 2) {

                for (int d = 0; (i + d < size) && (j + d < size); d++)
                    if (arr[i + d][j + d] == 2) {
                        count2++;
                        if (count2 == 5) {
                            whoWon = 2;
                        }
                    } else {
                        count2 = 0;
                    }

            }

        }

    }
    if (whoWon != 1 && whoWon != 2) {
        whoWon = 3;
    }

    return whoWon;
}

int game::diagonalCheckerPosSlope(int arr[15][15], int size) {
    int count1;
    int count2;
    int whoWon = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        count1 = 0;
        count2 = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == 1) {

                for (int d = 0; (i + d < size) && (j - d < size); d++)
                    if (arr[i + d][j - d] == 1) {
                        count1++;
                        if (count1 == 5) {
                            whoWon = 1;
                        }
                    } else {
                        count1 = 0;
                    }

            }
            if (arr[i][j] == 2) {

                for (int d = 0; (i + d < size) && (j - d < size); d++)
                    if (arr[i + d][j - d] == 2) {
                        count2++;
                        if (count2 == 5) {
                            whoWon = 2;
                        }
                    } else {
                        count2 = 0;
                    }
            }
        }

    }
    if (whoWon != 1 && whoWon != 2) {
        whoWon = 3;
    }
    return whoWon;
}
```

int main code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "game.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;



int main() {
    string inputSize = "input.txt";
    int size =0;
    srand(time(0));

    int arr[15][15];

    game Gomuko;

    size = Gomuko.getSize(inputSize, arr);
    if(size >=6 && size <=15){

    Gomuko.initZero(arr, size);
//  Gomuko.printArr(arr,size);

    Gomuko.Play(arr, size);

    Gomuko.printArr(arr,size);

    }else{
        cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The .h file of the class

```
#ifndef GAME_H_
#define GAME_H_

#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class game {
public:
    game();
    int getSize(string inputFileName, int dataArray[15][15]);
    void initZero(int arr[15][15], int size);
    void printArr(int arr[15][15], int size);
    void movePlayerOne(int arr[15][15], int size, int counter2);
    void movePlayerTwo(int arr[15][15], int size);
    void Play(int arr[15][15], int size);
    int PlayerOneSurroundRow(int arr[15][15],int size);
    int PlayerOneSurroundCol(int arr[15][15],int size);
    int findFirstMoveRow(int arr[15][15], int size);
    int findFirstMoveCol(int arr[15][15], int size);
    bool isValid(int newRow, int newCol, int size);
    int horizontalChecker(int arr[15][15], int size);
    int verticalChecker(int arr[15][15], int size);
    int diagonalCheckerNegSlope(int arr[15][15], int size);
    int diagonalCheckerPosSlope(int arr[15][15], int size);
    int WholeWinnerChecker(int arr[15][15], int size);
private:

    int randRow(int size);
    int randCol(int size);
};

#endif /* GAME_H_ */
```

And finally the .cpp file of the class

```
#include "game.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

game::game() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

int game::getSize(string inputFileName, int dataArray[15][15]) {//make between 6 and 15.
    ifstream inputData;

    int size = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    inputData.open(inputFileName);

    if (!inputData) {
        cout << "Cannot open the file \"" << inputFileName << "\"" << endl;
    }
    else {
        while (inputData >> size) {
            counter++;
        }
        cout << "There are " << counter << " board sizes in the inputFile"
                << endl;
        cout << "The size of the board is " << size << "x" << size << endl
                << endl;
    }
    return size;
}

void game::initZero(int arr[15][15], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void game::printArr(int arr[15][15], int size) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
}

int game::randRow(int size) {

    int randNoRow = 0;
    randNoRow = rand() % size;
    return randNoRow;
}

int game::randCol(int size) {

    int randNoCol = 0;
    randNoCol = rand() % size;
    return randNoCol;
}

int game::findFirstMoveRow(int arr[15][15], int size) {
    int positionRow;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
                positionRow = i;
            }
        }
    }

    return positionRow;
}

int game::findFirstMoveCol(int arr[15][15], int size) {
    int positionCol;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
                positionCol = j;
            }
        }
    }

    return positionCol;
}

int game::PlayerOneSurroundRow(int arr[15][15], int size) {

    int positionRow = game::findFirstMoveRow(arr, size);
//  cout << "The old row is " << positionRow << endl;

    int oldRow = positionRow;
    int randChoice = 0;
    int newRow = 0;

    randChoice = (rand() % 3);
//  cout << "randChoice Row case:  " << randChoice << endl;

    switch (randChoice) {
    case 0:
        newRow = oldRow - 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        newRow = oldRow;
        break;
    case 2:
        newRow = oldRow + 1;
        break;
    }
//  cout << "Test2" << endl << endl;
    if (newRow > size - 1) {
//      cout << "Row too big as Row is " << newRow << endl;
        newRow = newRow - 1;
//      cout << "Row is now " << newRow << endl;

    }
    if (newRow < 0) {
//      cout << "Row too small as row is " << newRow << endl;
        newRow = newRow + 1;
//      cout << "Row is now " << newRow << endl;

    }

//  cout << "The new row is: " << newRow << endl;

    return newRow;
}

int game::PlayerOneSurroundCol(int arr[15][15], int size) {

    int positionCol = findFirstMoveCol(arr, size);
//  cout << "The old col is " << positionCol << endl;

    int oldCol = positionCol;
    int randChoice = 0;
    int newCol = 0;

    randChoice = (rand() % 3);
    cout << "randChoice Col case: " << randChoice << endl;

    switch (randChoice) {
    case 0:
        newCol = oldCol - 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        newCol = oldCol;
        break;
    case 2:
        newCol = oldCol + 1;
        break;
    }
//  cout << "Test2" << endl << endl;
    if (newCol > size - 1) {
//      cout << "Col too big as is " << newCol << endl;
        newCol = newCol - 1;
//      cout << "Col is now " << newCol << endl;
    }
    if (newCol < 0) {
//      cout << "Col too small as is " << newCol << endl;
        newCol = newCol + 1;
//      cout << "Col is now " << newCol << endl;

    }

//  cout << "The new col is: " << newCol << endl;

    return newCol;
}

bool game::isValid(int newRow, int newCol, int size) {
    bool valid = false;
    if (((newRow < size) && (newCol < size))
            && ((newRow >= 0) && (newCol >= 0))) {
        valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
}

void game::movePlayerOne(int arr[15][15], int size, int counter2) {

    int newRow = 0;
    int newCol = 0;
    int oldRow = 0;
    int oldCol = 0;
    int count3 = 0;

    if (counter2 == 0) {
        oldRow = randRow(size);
        oldCol = randCol(size);

        arr[oldRow][oldCol] = 1;
//      cout << "Test1" << endl << endl << endl;
        counter2++;
    }

    else {

//      cout << "Test 3" << endl;

        newRow = game::PlayerOneSurroundRow(arr, size);
        newCol = game::PlayerOneSurroundCol(arr, size);

        if (arr[newRow][newCol] == 0 && isValid(newRow, newCol, size)) {
            arr[newRow][newCol] = 1;
//          cout << "Test4" << endl;
//          cout << "randNoRow = " << newRow << endl;
//          cout << "randNoCol = " << newCol << endl;

            oldRow = newRow;
            oldCol = newCol;
        }

        else if ((arr[newRow][newCol] == 1) || (arr[newRow][newCol] == 2)
                || (newRow > size) || (newCol > size) || (newRow < 0)
                || (newCol < 0)) {
            cout
                    << "There has been a match, or even out of bounds, going again. "
                    << endl << endl;

            while ((arr[newRow][newCol] == 1) || (arr[newRow][newCol] == 2)) {

//              cout << "Test5" << endl;
                newRow = game::PlayerOneSurroundRow(arr, size);
                newCol = game::PlayerOneSurroundCol(arr, size);

//              cout << "randNoRow = " << newRow << endl;
//              cout << "randNoCol = " << newCol << endl;

                count3++;
                if ((arr[newRow][newCol] != 1 && arr[newRow][newCol] != 2)
                        && isValid(newRow, newCol, size)) {
                    arr[newRow][newCol] = 1;
//                  cout << "Test6" << endl;
//
//                  cout << "randNoRow = " << newRow << endl;
//                  cout << "randNoCol = " << newCol << endl;

                    oldRow = newRow;
                    oldCol = newCol;
                    break;
                }

                if (count3++ > 3) {
//                  cout << "Test 7" << endl;
//                  newRow = randRow(size);
//                  newCol = randCol(size);
                    while (arr[newRow][newCol] == 1 || arr[newRow][newCol] == 2) {
                        newRow = randRow(size);
                        newCol = randCol(size);
//                      cout << "Test 8" << endl;
//                      cout << "randNoRow = " << newRow << endl;
//                      cout << "randNoCol = " << newCol << endl;

                        if (arr[newRow][newCol] == 0) {
                            arr[newRow][newCol] = 1;
//                          cout << "Test 9" << endl;
//                          cout << "randNoRow = " << newRow << endl;
//                          cout << "randNoCol = " << newCol << endl;
                            oldRow = newRow;
                            oldCol = newCol;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

void game::movePlayerTwo(int arr[15][15], int size) {

//  cout << "Test" << endl;

    int randNoRow = 0;
    int randNoCol = 0;

    randNoRow = randRow(size);
    cout << "randNoRow = " << randNoRow << endl;

    randNoCol = randCol(size);
    cout << "randNoCol = " << randNoCol << endl;

    cout << endl;

    if ((arr[randNoRow][randNoCol] == 1) || (arr[randNoRow][randNoCol] == 2)) {
        //cout << "There has been a match, going again. " << endl << endl;
        while ((arr[randNoRow][randNoCol] == 1)
                || (arr[randNoRow][randNoCol] == 2)) {

            int randNoRow = 0;
            int randNoCol = 0;

            randNoRow = randRow(size);
            //cout << "randNoRow = " << randNoRow << endl;

            randNoCol = randCol(size);
            //cout << "randNoCol = " << randNoCol << endl;

            //cout << endl;

            if (arr[randNoRow][randNoCol] == 0) {
                arr[randNoRow][randNoCol] = 2;
                break;
            }
        }

    } else {
        arr[randNoRow][randNoCol] = 2;
    }
}

int game::horizontalChecker(int arr[15][15], int size) {
    int count1;
    int count2;
    int whoWon = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        count1 = 0;
        count2 = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
                count1++;
                if (count1 == 5) {
                    whoWon = 1;
                }

            } else {
                count1 = 0;
            }
            if (arr[j][i] == 2) {
                count2++;
                if (count2 == 5) {
                    whoWon = 2;
                }

            } else {
                count2 = 0;
            }

        }
        if (whoWon != 1 && whoWon != 2) {
            whoWon = 3;
        }
    }
    return whoWon;
}

int game::verticalChecker(int arr[15][15], int size) {
    int count1;
    int count2;
    int whoWon = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        count1 = 0;
        count2 = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[j][i] == 1) {
                count1++;
                if (count1 == 5) {
                    whoWon = 1;
                }

            } else {
                count1 = 0;
            }
            if (arr[j][i] == 2) {
                count2++;
                if (count2 == 5) {
                    whoWon = 2;
                }

            } else {
                count2 = 0;
            }

        }
        if (whoWon != 1 && whoWon != 2) {
            whoWon = 3;
        }
    }
    return whoWon;
}
int game::diagonalCheckerNegSlope(int arr[15][15], int size) {
    int count1;
    int count2;
    int whoWon = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        count1 = 0;
        count2 = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[j][i] == 1) {

                for (int d = 0; (i + d < size) && (j + d < size); d++)
                    if (arr[i + d][j + d] == 1) {
                        count1++;
                        if (count1 == 5) {
                            whoWon = 1;
                        }
                    } else {
                        count1 = 0;
                    }

            }
            if (arr[j][i] == 2) {

                for (int d = 0; (i + d < size) && (j + d < size); d++)
                    if (arr[i + d][j + d] == 2) {
                        count2++;
                        if (count2 == 5) {
                            whoWon = 2;
                        }
                    } else {
                        count2 = 0;
                    }

            }

        }

    }
    if (whoWon != 1 && whoWon != 2) {
        whoWon = 3;
    }

    return whoWon;
}

int game::diagonalCheckerPosSlope(int arr[15][15], int size) {
    int count1;
    int count2;
    int whoWon = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        count1 = 0;
        count2 = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == 1) {

                for (int d = 0; (i + d < size) && (j - d < size); d++)
                    if (arr[i + d][j - d] == 1) {
                        count1++;
                        if (count1 == 5) {
                            whoWon = 1;
                        }
                    } else {
                        count1 = 0;
                    }

            }
            if (arr[i][j] == 2) {

                for (int d = 0; (i + d < size) && (j - d < size); d++)
                    if (arr[i + d][j - d] == 2) {
                        count2++;
                        if (count2 == 5) {
                            whoWon = 2;
                        }
                    } else {
                        count2 = 0;
                    }
            }
        }

    }
    if (whoWon != 1 && whoWon != 2) {
        whoWon = 3;
    }
    return whoWon;
}

int game::WholeWinnerChecker(int arr[15][15], int size) {
    int finalWinner = 0;
    int outcome1 = horizontalChecker(arr, size);
    if ((outcome1 == 1) || (outcome1 == 2)) {
        finalWinner = outcome1;
        cout << "Horizontal Win" << endl;
    }
    int outcome2 = verticalChecker(arr, size);
    if ((outcome2 == 1) || (outcome2 == 2)) {
        finalWinner = outcome2;
        cout << "Vertical Win" << endl;
    }
    int outcome3 = diagonalCheckerPosSlope(arr, size);
    if ((outcome3 == 1) || (outcome3 == 2)) {
        finalWinner = outcome3;
        cout << "Diag Pos Win" << endl;
    }
    int outcome4 = diagonalCheckerNegSlope(arr, size);
    if ((outcome4 == 1) || (outcome4 == 2)) {
        finalWinner = outcome4;
        cout << "Diag Neg Win" << endl;
    }

    else if ((finalWinner != 1) && (finalWinner != 2)) {
        finalWinner = 3;
    }

    return finalWinner;
}

void game::Play(int arr[15][15], int size) {
    int counter = 0;
    int Winner=0;
    int boardFull= size*size;
        while(((Winner != 1)&&(Winner != 2))&& (counter < boardFull)){
        cout << "This is turn " << counter + 1 << endl;
        if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            cout << "PlayerOne: " << endl;
            game::movePlayerOne(arr, size, counter);
            if (counter >= 4) {
                Winner = game::WholeWinnerChecker(arr, size);
                if(Winner ==1){
                cout << endl <<"======================" << endl;
                cout << "Winner = " << Winner << endl;
                cout <<"======================" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        if (counter % 2 == 1) {
            cout << "PlayerTwo:" << endl;
            game::movePlayerTwo(arr, size);
            if (counter >= 5) {
                Winner = game::WholeWinnerChecker(arr, size);
                if (Winner == 2) {
                    cout << endl << "======================" << endl;
                    cout << "Winner = " << Winner << endl;
                    cout << "======================" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        if(counter == boardFull){
            cout << "Draw" << endl;
        }

        counter++;

    }

}
```

I have also been using an input of

```
6
```

Comment: That is what's called a LOT of code. It doesn't fit well on a Q&A site like Stack Overflow because the volume of it either unnecessarily conceals the problem or guarantees that the problem will be so specific that any solutions given will be utterly worthless to futre askers. I strongly recommend crafting a [mre] (a MRE), and if you make it through the making of the MRE without finding and fixing the mistake yourself, replace the code in the question with the MRE.

Comment: learn to use your debugger. It will help you out here, more then SO can. Should take 10 mins at most to work out debugger basics

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the tip. So I tried making a MRE and the diagonal checker works well there. However, something isn't working when it is put together in the main code that's why decided to add the rest of the code below, and was hoping someone would be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be that you don't set `count1` and `count2` inside the j-loop, but rather count on the variable being reset in the `else` statement. But if your d-loop ends before the `else` statement is executed (`(i + d < size) && (j - d < size)` becomes false "prematurely") then the counter is not reset. Solution: move the zero-initialization to inside the j-loop.

Some improvements:

If lots of methods have the same parameter (such as `int arr[15][15]` and `int size`) then this could be the sign that these parameters should become members of the class.

It is possible to have only one checker function. Parameters of this function would be the direction of the search (int deltaX, int deltaY), and also the value that is being checked (1 or 2). Delta-values for all 8 directions are these:

(1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1)

So, in your d-loop you would not add or subtract `d` to and from `i` and `j`, but you would always add `deltaX` to `i`, and `deltaY` to `j`.

Also, a bit advanced, but also fun. It is possible to arrange the code in such a way that you can have three types of games: human vs human, human vs computer, computer vs computer. You just for instance assign object of a class `HumanPlayer` to player 1 and object of a class `ComputerPlayer` to player 2. This would enable you to pick who plays first, and also have several algorithms battling it out. Both classes would have to be derived from the base class `Player` with some known methods (like 'move'), and some `GameCoordinator` would in a loop call this method 'move' on both objects, update the game state, and check if game has ended.